# Search Query Line

Tags: javascript, php

When I click the category for the License, nothing happens.

```
  <script>
function goToPage( select1 ) {

  var node = document.getElementById( select1 );

  if( node &&
    node.tagName == "SELECT" ) {

    // Go to web page defined by the VALUE attribute of the OPTION element

    window.location.href = node.options[node.selectedIndex].value;

  } // endif


}
</script>  
                   <center><label for="select1">Go to Marker</label></center>
                <select id="select1" onChange="goToPage('select1')">
                  <?php
                    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("dbposo",$conn);

                    $news=mysql_query("select id,license from tblviolator");

                    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($news))
                        {
                            $id=$data['id'];
                            $license=$data['license'];

                            print "
                                <option value='#X$id'>$license</option>
                            ";
                        }
                    ?>  

                  </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Id searching on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985687/id-searching-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score -1):

This works fine for me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function goToPage(select1) {

        var node = document.getElementById(select1);

        if (node && node.tagName == "SELECT") {

            // Go to web page defined by the VALUE attribute of the OPTION element

            window.location.href = node.options[node.selectedIndex].value;

        } // endif


    }
</script>
<center>
    <label for="select1">Go to Marker</label>
</center>
<select id="select1" onChange="goToPage('select1')">
    <option value="#X1">1</option>
    <option value="#X2">2</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a name="X1">1</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a name="X2">2</a>
```

Comment: I am using a table, but how come nothing is happening ?

Comment: Are your anchor-name tags in the same page?

Comment: My anchor-name is coming from my database sir. And I'm getting the value $license coming from my databse

Comment: the <a name=""> tag, where is that? It's not in your code.

Comment: Can I use <a name="$license">$license</a> ?

Comment: I am using this code <td width='80px'><center><a href='oldrecord.php?n=$link'><font color='#00FF00'>$license</font></a></center><br>

Comment: Please read more about the A tag's name attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp