# Id searching on the same page

Tags: javascript, php

When I click the category for the License, nothing happens.

```
  <script>
function goToPage( select1 ) {

  var node = document.getElementById( select1 );

  if( node &&
    node.tagName == "SELECT" ) {

    // Go to web page defined by the VALUE attribute of the OPTION element

    window.location.href = node.options[node.selectedIndex].value;

  } // endif


}
</script>  
                   <center><label for="select1">Go to Marker</label></center>
                <select id="select1" onChange="goToPage('select1')">
                  <?php
                    $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                    mysql_select_db("dbposo",$conn);

                    $news=mysql_query("select id,license from tblviolator");

                    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($news))
                        {
                            $id=$data['id'];
                            $license=$data['license'];

                            print "
                                <option value='#X$id'>$license</option>
                            ";
                        }
                    ?>  

                  </select>
```

Comment: Your URL should end up looking like example.com/mypage.php#X123 - is this the case?

Comment: getelementbyid('select1') try giving quotes

Comment: Yes sir, what should i do? :(

Comment: @CodingAnt nothing happened :(

Comment: Have you got any error on firebug console?

Comment: I have no error sir, no error is appearing even in my php code

Comment: try to check for JS error in console

Comment: where to check that console sir?

Comment: What type of elements is your option value referring to?? input or div or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search Query Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984821/search-query-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply write your select tag as follows without calling the function. if you only want to redirect on the value of your select box

```
<select id="select1" onChange="window.location.href=this.value;">
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
<script>
var current_url = window.location.href ;
function goToPage(val) {

    window.location.href = current_url+val;
}
</script> 

<select id="select1" onChange="goToPage(this.value);">
```

Comment: thank you sir :) but i can't still vote :) i'll vote for you if i have 15 reputation :)